# How to Set Access Request for each MySite Users Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, onedrive-for-business, mysites

So, we have our MySites setup and everyone has been creating their MySite.  However, we noticed that the Access Request settings for each MySite was "someone@example.com" and not the Owner of the MySite which I was expecting.

Is this by design or does anyone have a PowerShell script to change this to the MySite Owners e-mail?

Actually, this is under One Drive for Business under Site Settings=>Site Permissions.

Maybe I should look into writing a PowerShell script that will populate the Access Request e-mail address from their UserProfile.

Comment: Maybe I should look into writing a PowerShell script that will populate the Access Request e-mail address from their UserProfile.

Answer (score 0):

How did you enable Access Request on each My Site?

Per my test, there is no Access Request settings under Site permissions on each my site.

If you want to change the request access email via PowerShell command, you can check the blog below:

[Manage Access Request Settings in SharePoint 2013](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/manage-access-request-settings-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

Comment: If you go to "http://mysite.contoso.com/personal/contoso_username/_layouts/15/user.aspx" you will see the Access Request Settings in the Ribbon.  I did not enable it, all I did was provision mysites.

Comment: This is actually located One Drive for Business under Site Settings=>Site Permissions. You will see "Access Requests"